# Can I put a comma after a conjunction and before a prepositional phrase?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, prepositional-phrases

I'm pretty sure the rule is not to put a comma after a conjunction, but sometimes it just seems like that prepositional phrase needs to be comma'd off. Is it just plain wrong to put the comma right after the conjunction?

Ex: I went to the store to buy eggs and milk and, though I shouldn't, I bought a candy bar too.

Comment: That looks perfectly fine to me:  the commas act like parentheses in this case.  I'll leave it for someone with more formal knowledge to explain why (or contradict me).

Comment: Your example actually involves a subordinate clause and not a prepositional phrase, but the principle is the same. Here is an example with a prepositional phrase: "She found a complete edition of Shaw's plays and prefaces, and, in a back room, [her brother found] a first edition of *Three Plays for Puritans."* (Bracketed words are supplied to illustrate the option of having complete clauses before and after the *and.)* Inserting the optional comma *before* the *and* seems to me desirable in such a case.